# virtualenv activate does not work

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment to test an api.

I can create the environment just fine using `virtualenv test`, then I can cd into it.  When I try to run `activate`, I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Bright Bridge\Desktop\autocomplete_demo\Scripts> activate
activate : The term 'activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ activate
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: The command activate was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current
 location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\activate". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

I recently updated windows, and it replaced the cmd with Windows Powershell.  My virtualenv worked fine with the cmd, so I suspect it may have to do with the way the Powershell does things.

How can I activate the virtualenv?

Comment: If you press `WindowsKey + R`, and type `cmd` when the box comes up, does it still bring up powershell?

Comment: No, it brings up the cmd.  I have just been navigating to it by right clicking the start button.  I'll see if it works through the cmd.

Comment: It works in the cmd.  You should post this as an answer so I can accept this.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad it worked out! That's quite odd that powershell comes up instead.

Comment: http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you press `WindowsKey + R`, and type `cmd` when the box comes up, it should bring up the command line interface instead of powershell!

Comment: And what are you meant to do with it??

Comment: This did work for me as I used ``.\env\Scripts\activate`` But can anyone tell me why is my poweshell giving the same error as in the question above, Because it was working fine before today. Suddenly it started giving me this error.

Answer (score 11):

For those of you still interested, the output gives you the answer:

> If you trust this command, instead type: ".\activate".

So use a relative path name to run the activate script in powershell, or use an absolute path

Answer (score 7):

You need to set windows execution policies. According to official documentation of virtualenv.

Run in powershell `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUse`

Now you can activate virtual env. using `\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

Hope it solves it!

Comment: This solved the issue for me, in my case, I had to run it with the "./" at the beginning of the path in addition to this solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Just Enter one PowerShell Command**

1. .\Scripts\activate

   Rather Then
2. ./Scripts/activate

Answer (score 2):

You basically needs to set execution policy for PowerShell

Step 1: Run PowerShell as Administartor

Step 2: Run Below Command

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

After successfull run, You will be able to activate vertual environemnt.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Execute **.\activate** instead of **activate**

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

after jumping to Scripts folder
cd Scripts
just write .\activate
It works perfectly
[see here on youtube](https://youtu.be/dA4sxEyvA1Y)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on visual studio code then you have to change the command prompt type.

- Click on the **+** icon in the terminal
- Change PowerShell to **Command Prompt**
- Navigate to **Scripts** folder, & execute **activate**

It might help developers who are using **Visual Studio Code** IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my windows I use this way with  gitbash

```
cd .myenv/Scripts
```

then navigate and type

```
activate
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

- first make virtualenv with `virtualenv pymote_env`
- Activate environment: `pymote_env\Scripts\activate`
- in your case:-

  - first make virtualenv with `virtualenv test`
  - Activate environment: `test\Scripts\activate`
- http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

Answer (score 0):

Use command pompt instead of using power-shell
and run the same command

[image]

this should work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all variants it works with  **C:...venv\scripts .\activate.ps1**
But before that, I changed my **ExecutionPolicy** to **RemoteSigned**. You can do it by next steps.

1. Enter **Set-ExecutionPolicy**
2. Enter **RemoteSigned**
3. System should ask you if u wish to save changes. Answer with "Y"
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP2Xm.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.Just add the complete path in cmd like this " cd.\pyenvDjango\Scripts" and press enter,

2. Now you see the complete directory path in which you are.
3. Now just type ".\activate".
4. this will activate your env.

**NOTE:- try this in cmd not in vs code terminal or any where**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in vscode after updating windows. What worked for me is:

1. Navigating to the scripts folder of the target virtual environment
2. typing `.\activate`.