# How to activate python virtual environment in VS code terminal?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a python virtual environment using VS code editor.
a virtual environment is created successfully but I am not able to activate it.

[image]

when I am trying to activate my virtual env

[image]

I have also tried with "activate.bat"

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv activate does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194427/virtualenv-activate-does-not-work)

Answer (score 19):

I was trying to activate virtual env command in PowerShell which is by default selected in VS Code, that why it was giving me an error.

we can select different terminal(PowerShell, Command Prompt, Git bash) in VS code. so I have just selected cmd(Command Prompt) and now it is working.

[image]

Comment: it seems to be fixed with powershell 7 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62635417/8275142

Answer (score 3):

You are using Powershell in your terminal (as denoted by PS) in the begining of every line in the terminal. You can switch to cmd and it will work. To do this, check the above asnwer by Sandeep Bhatt. If the option is not available, follow these steps,

1. Open commands search (use Ctrl+Shift+P or from menu View->Command Palette...) while terminal is open
2. In command box that appears, type "Terminal: Select Default Shell" and select it.
3. All the available commands which are in path will be listed. Select command prompt here.
4. Once this is done, you can change into cmd by clicking the plus icon [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnOzW.png)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using powershell and your python virtual environment is in the 'venv' folder then you'll need to source the Activate.ps1 script by using the following command

```
 . .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

The dot (.) is the equivalent of "source" command in powershell.
After sourcing Activate.ps1 the virtual environment commands activate and deactivate will work.

With newer versions of virtual environments (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6931) you can also activate the environment as in the following example:

```
& .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the shell like here in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7D7w.png)
change it to git bash or terminal of windows, and use the command "source FolderNameOfVirtualenviremenrts/Scripts/activate" (this command is for git-bash terminal)

Answer (score 1):

The terminal in vs code by default uses Powershell or PS. If you are mostly coding in python and switching environments frequently ,set the default terminal to CMD.
[screnshots attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7fy0.png)
You are good to go.

Comment: Why should we switch from PowerShell to cmd? It's ancient. PowerShell is a much better shell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work now if you are in powershell:

```
.\Venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode terminal you have two ways to activate the virtual enviroment.

in pwsh: first make sure the terminal was inside the root directory of you env:

```
PS C:\meuuser\workspace\> cd path/to/venv*_diretory.
PS C:\meuuser\workspace\Nome_diretório_venv>
```

now you can use the following command:

```
PS C:\meuuser\workspace\Nome_diretório_venv> .\Script\activate.ps1
```

CMD terminal:

```
C:\meuuser\workspace\Nome_diretório_venv>.\Script\activate.bat
```

or you can use only this in both options:

```
.\Script\activate
```

when virtual enviromment is on you'll see somenthing like this:

```
(venv) PS C:\meuuser\workspace\Nome_diretório_venv>
```

**the real problem is that you are inside the Script folder, not root folder of your env.**

your root folder is where you find the *pyvenv.cfg* file

```
PS C:\meuuser\workspace\Nome_diretório_venv\Script> cd..
PS C:\meuuser\workspace\Nome_diretório_venv> .\Script\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows system, after opening a Powershell terminal in vscode
You need to run the two lines below: first setting execution policy then activating virtual environment.

```
PS C:\mydocs\python> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope CurrentUser

PS C:\mydocs\python> . .\.venv\Scripts\activate.ps1

Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
File C:\mydocs\python\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 is published by CN=Python Software Foundation, O=Python Software   
Foundation, L=Beaverton, S=Oregon, C=US and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted
publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"): A
(.venv) PS C:\mydocs\python>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to project root folder, which contains hidden folder `.venv`. Check that folder is actually present in current location:

```
ls -la
```

Then activate virtual environment:

```
source ./.venv/bin/activate
```

`source` command executes script `activate` in the current terminal session

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear what you're using to create the virtual environment, and I presume that you're simply accessing the terminal from VSCode.

Try `source activate <env_name>` to start your environment.

Comment: `source` command works in linux. Looks like the user is trying in Windows. This isn't going to help I guess.

Comment: Gah. You're right, of course.