# How to activate conda environment in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, miniconda

I created a virtual environment using `miniconda`. I'm using Visual Studio Code with Mask rcnn, but I can't start the virtual environment in Visual Studio Code, I get an `error.Sevinirim`

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Please read this: https://py-vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files/venv.html#selecting-switching-between-the-environments-in-vs-code

> Press ctrl+shift+P to open VS Code’s command palette.
>
> Type interpreter in the search box. And select the Python: Select
> Interpreter option. You should see a list of all the available (both
> conda and virtual environments are shown) python environments. You
> should also see your recently created myenv environment there. Toggle
> and select your environment and you are good to go.

After ctrl+shift+P

[image]

Select `conda` env from a list

[image]

Comment: this works "Select interpreter" how do i persist it for this workspace ?

Comment: In my experience, using the "Select interpreter" menu does persist the setting of the virtual environment for this workspace. From this documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_general-python-settings) You can try setting the `python.defaultInterpreterPath` setting variable.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because `conda activate env-name` won't work in a VS Code Powershell (PS) terminal. When opening terminal in Windows VS Code, this is typically the default terminal shell.

A couple solutions:

1. Open a new VS Code terminal session that uses Command Prompt (cmd) as its shell - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57320144/5972778)
2. Change your default shell to cmd (instructions below)

[From VS Code doc's](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments):
Conda environments can't be automatically activated in the VS Code Integrated Terminal if the default shell is set to PowerShell. To change the shell, see [Integrated terminal - Terminal profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles).